# Correct redirecton to www in htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have problem with correct redirection rule to www in my .htaccess file.

Nothing works properly instead standard

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Every other rule returns `404 File Not Found` on every subpage, except main page.

Does anybody have an idea how to do this without 404 error?

[image: error for address - example.com/kontakt]

error for address - example.com/kontakt

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
# [NC] is a case-insensitive match
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

try this :)

Comment: Thanks for answer but unfortunately none of above works. Both rules return 404 File Not Found when entering subpage.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess

```
> RewriteEngine on 
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

also change the url to www to your prefix_options table if needed

Comment: Still the same :( - 404 Not Found error. _options table has proper url, with www.

Comment: can i see something to diagnose properly ?

Comment: What do you want to see exactly? I'd really like to give you access but I'm afraid I can't :( Only some screenshots or code copy.

Comment: Please share the screenshot of error on your webpage, .htaccess screenshot.

Comment: I updated post with screenshot. Thanks for your help!

Comment: .htaccess has currently standard rule, as in post. All different combinations with redirection to www, gives 404 error on subpages. Database and wordpress settings are set up to redirect to www domain. I also thought about setting this redirection in my hosting settings, but support's instruction says that the best way is to properly edit .htaccess file.